# Eigen runtime alignment assertions with struct members on gcc 9.3 with C++ 17

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, eigen

I am getting run-time alignment assertions with Eigen 3.3.7 compiling with gcc version 9.3 and `-std=c++17 -O0`.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

struct axis_result                          // <-- Asserting from here
{
    ...
    double              cal_maximum_time;
    Eigen::Vector2d     unit_vector;
    bool                has_error;
    ...
};

class cal_axis_diagnostics
{
    ...
public:
    cal_axis_diagnostics() {}               // <- In stack-frame
    ...
private:
    ...
    axis_result axis_;
    ...
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ...
    auto cal = new cal_axis_diagnostics();  // <- In stack-frame
    ...
}
```

The run-time assertion points me to http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html, which states that the problem should disappear with a sufficiently recent compiler (GCC >= 7 with C++ 17). Obviously this is not the case for me.

I already tried:

1. Adding `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` to the struct to inject the alignment operator new,
2. Adding `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` to classes that have `axis_result` members.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** I figured out that implicit construction of `axis_` (Which contains an `Eigen` type) is causing the issue. Somehow, GCC bypasses the Eigen alignment mechanisms if the implicit construction of `axis_` is allowed. Explicitly adding `axis_` to the initializer list fixes the issue:

```
class cal_axis_diagnostics
{
    ...
public:
    cal_axis_diagnostics()
    : axis_{}                             // <- Note explicit construction
                                          //    of axis_ in initializer list
    {}
    ...
private:
    ...
    axis_result axis_;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Please make sure that your [mre] actually reproduces the problem. There should be no problem at all with only SSE2 (the default) when compiling for 64bit. When activating AVX, you may have alignment problems for objects that benefit from being 256bit aligned (but also only prior to C++17): https://godbolt.org/z/3jnq73

Comment: Thanks @chtz. I trimmed down the code to the minimal example, and the problem is not reproducible any more, so I need to scale back up to find the point where it can be reproduced. I will get back to you on this.

Comment: Hi @chtz,
After trying to tease out a minimal implementation that triggers the bug, I found the cause: implicit construction of class members containing Eigen types. If some class members of a class are classes or structs containing Eigen types, you have to explicitly add their constructors to the initializer list. The following modification fixes the issue and makes the assertion go away: `cal_axis_diagnostics(): axis_{}`